# Cannot open: c:\users\...\temp\package.cab when running Process.Start

Tags: c#, scripting, text-files, temp

Hello I got this little script of microsoft:

```
@echo off
rem *** Author: T. Wittrock, Kiel ***

if not exist "%TEMP%\wsusscn2.cab" (
  .\bin\wget.exe -N -i .\static\StaticDownloadLinks-wsus.txt -P "%TEMP%"
  if exist "%TEMP%\wuredist.cab" del "%TEMP%\wuredist.cab"
  if exist "%TEMP%\WindowsUpdateAgent30-x64.exe" del "%TEMP%\WindowsUpdateAgent30-x64.exe"
  if exist "%TEMP%\WindowsUpdateAgent30-x86.exe" del "%TEMP%\WindowsUpdateAgent30-x86.exe"
)
if exist "%TEMP%\package.cab" del "%TEMP%\package.cab"
if exist "%TEMP%\package.xml" del "%TEMP%\package.xml"
%SystemRoot%\System32\expand.exe "%TEMP%\wsusscn2.cab" -F:package.cab "%TEMP%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\expand.exe "%TEMP%\package.cab" "%TEMP%\package.xml"
del "%TEMP%\package.cab"


%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //Nologo //E:vbs .\cmd\XSLT.vbs "%TEMP%\package.xml" .\xslt\ExtractDownloadLinks-w60-x64-glb.xsl "%TEMP%\DownloadLinks-all.txt"


%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //Nologo //E:vbs .\cmd\XSLT.vbs "%TEMP%\package.xml" .\xslt\ExtractDownloadLinks-w60-x86-glb.xsl "%TEMP%\DownloadLinks-all.txt"

del "%TEMP%\package.xml"
del "%TEMP%\wsusscn2.cab"

:EoF
```

I runs perfectly when I double click it.
I try to open it through C# with the follow code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\trunk-r664\\trunk\\ExtractDownloadLinks-all");
```

But when I run this it gives a error in the cmd, saying:

```
Can not open input file: c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\packacge.cab
Can not open input file: c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\wsusscn2.cab
```

I guess the best option to fix this is to chance the script of Microsoft? But I have no idea how. Or maybe there is a solution in C# for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Worth checking that the line `.\bin\wget.exe -N -i .\static\StaticDownloadLinks-wsus.txt -P "%TEMP%"` is acting as expected, as the files `wsusscn2.cab` and `package.cab` are not in `%TEMP%` when you execute `expand.exe`.

Comment: True, but why would it work when I double click ExtractDownloadLinks-all , but when I do the same in C# it wont work? Do I first have to load the whole trunk-map in C# or something like that to make it work? I have lterally no idea

Comment: If I were to venture a guess, I would suggest that the output from `wget.exe` is not as it is when you run this directly.  You may want to look into the working directory being used by C#, as your relative paths (such as `.\static\StaticDownloadLinks-wsus.txt` may end up in a different location from the one you are expecting them to.

Answer (score 0):

I got help of someone who knows a lot about wsus offline and knows how to script. I ask the same question on here: http://forums.wsusoffline.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5001&p=15991#p15991 And got this answer: 
Special thanks to "Aker"!

```
System.Diagnostics.Process wsusou = new Process();
            wsusou.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            wsusou.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/k C:\Users\me\Desktop\trunk-r664\trunk\ExtractDownloadLinks-all.cmd"; // replace "/k" with "/c", if cmd should auto-close
            wsusou.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\trunk-r664\trunk";
            wsusou.Start();
            while (wsusou.HasExited == false)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            wsusou.Dispose();
```